# Laravel UpdateOrCreate

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to if there are records just update and if there are not records just create. Problem is:

> Already has records case: It creates records when there are already have record in database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $time = $request->input('time');
        foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
            Choice::UpdateOrCreate([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'time'  => $time,
                'topic_id' => $key,
                'question_number' => $value,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the unique for each record, **user_id** and **topic_id**? And what is the field that should be updated?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Comment: **question_number** and **topic_id** should be updated.

Comment: And to search the record you will need just `user_id` ?

Comment: Method is `updateOrCreate([], [])` - starting with lower case. That method accepts two arrays, first one that you are checking possibly existing values and second with data to be updated created. Something like `Choice::updateOrCreate(['user_id' => Auth::id(), 'time' => $time], ['topic_id' => $key, 'question_number' => $value]);`.

Answer (score 2):

use this way :

```
    $matchThese=array('user_id' => Auth::id())

    Choice::updateOrCreate($matchThese,['topic_id'=>$key,'question_number' => $value,'time' => $time]);
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '$key' for column 'topic_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `choices` (`user_id`, `topic_id`, `question_number`, `time`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, $key, 20, 30:01, 2018-06-06 17:34:29, 2018-06-06 17:34:29))`

Comment: use value of `$key`

Comment: It didn't foreach data as key. just created last one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass two parameters to the `UpdateOrCreate` the first is the `attributes` of searching records the second is the `values` in the doc of the method we have :

> Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.

So if you search the record just with the `user_id` you have to do it like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $time = $request->input('time');
    foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
        Choice::UpdateOrCreate([
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
         ],
         [
            'time'  => $time,
            'topic_id' => $key,
            'question_number' => $value,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't foreach data as key. just created last one.

Comment: What do you mean by _It didn't foreach data as key._ ?

Comment: `foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {` it's not working anymore. I just don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

As per Rest Update in crud *UpdateOrCreate* creates a record if it doesn't finds a matching record. So, you format of Choice::UpdateOrCreate must be like this

```
Choice::updateOrCreate(['user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'time'  => $time,], [
                    'topic_id' => $key,
                    'question_number' => $value,
                ])
```

where ['user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'time'  => $time,] is the check for existance of a record.

Comment: `Undefined variable: id`

Comment: And its the same as mine. creates new ones. updates old ones.

Comment: i know this best possible solution for kind of case provided by user .

Comment: preferably i would recommend to create a post and patch call seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the code in the loop with this:

```
...
Choice::UpdateOrCreate(
    ['user_id' => Auth::id(), 'time' => $time],
    ['topic_id' => $key, 'question_number' => $value]
);
...
```

This will search for a record of user at specific time and create one if there is not, but if there is it will update its topic_id and question_number.

Comment: It didn't foreach data as key. just created last one.